# Create new cookie with Firefox Developer Tool

Tags: firefox, cookies

I'm using Firefox latest version 53.0.3 on Ubuntu Linux, and I can't find how to create a new cookie with the **Storage Inspector** tab in the **Developer Tools**.

I can edit and delete existent ones, but there is no button or any option to create new ones, also using the **Console** I can't replace the existent cookies with something like this `document.cookie = 'key=value;...'`, so... ¿Is there a way to do this without installing thirty party addons with Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally looks like the FF team added a button with this feature. I have FF 55.0.2, and now there is a button to add new cookies:

[image: Firefox 55 Add Cookie Button]

**UPDATED:**

At some point the "Storage" tab was redesigned a bit and the **+** icon to add a new cookie now is at the top right corner, here is screenshot of how it looks like in the latest Firefox, version 83:

[image: Firefox 83 Add Cookie Button]

Comment: Because icons look different in newer Versions: "Almacenamiento" is "Storage" or "Web-Speicher" in German.

Comment: Does not work with localhost ‍♂️ User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0 build ID: 20210415204500
Does not show any values in list, clicking button do nothing. :/

Comment: Agreed -- can't add a new cookie for localhost. This is absurd.

Comment: It also doesn't work if you're on a page that returns JSON. It looks like it still creates a new cookie, but it uses some random uuid as the domain, so it doesn't show up in the list, or apply to the page you're on. What a funky bug.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a way to do this with embeded developer tools. The only way i found is installing the [editthiscookie extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/user/editthiscookie/?src=api)